# UIVisualEffectView In LoadVIew()

Tags: ios, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to add visualEffect to a view which is working fine on iOS10 and prior versions... but on iOS 11 it crashing. Error reason is listed below:

```
 has been added as a subview to <UIVisualEffectView: 0x7feabe90d170; frame = (0 0; 375 812); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000006257c0>>. Do not add subviews directly to the visual effect view itself, instead add them to the -contentView."
```

I'm using the following code:

```
 override func loadView() { 
    super.loadView()

    // create the blur view
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
    if let oldView = view {
        blurView.frame = view.frame
        oldView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurView.contentView.addSubview(oldView)
        blurView.contentView.pinParentAllDirections(oldView)
    }
    view = blurView
}
```

The strange thing is when I add this code in viewDidload it's passing the crash... Anybody please help me understand the main problem or am I missing anything in-terms of iOS11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should not call `super.loadView()` from `loadView` function.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the
>   view controller, you must not override this method.

We had something similar and fixed it by also moving the code out of `loadView` method. as loadView is used to construct the view and not a point in time where you want to customize your view.

Comment: Did you try removing the super.loadView() as suggested by @Hani Ibrahim?

Comment: I did right now.. but it went into an infinit loop inside loadView() for some reason

Comment: Try creating a new UIView and assign it to self.view. That will fix the issue.

Comment: you mean uiview as container to the visual and then add them all to the root ?

Comment: @hegab I think it entered an infinite loop because calling `view` while the view is not loaded probably leads to call `loadView` to load the view and so on

Answer (score 1):

For all intent and purposes, you should never override loadView or call it yourself.  You should instead override `awakeFromNib()` or `viewDidLoad()` to further customize your view before it is displayed on the screen.

You can also do last second touch up to your view before it appears anywhere in the `viewWillAppear(animated:)`.